# JWT generation and genric ussage in Karate framework

Tags: api, karate

My scenario is I have to encode the token and secret using base encoding then generate a JWT token through API, which will give response like:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJmOWJlYmFjYjVhMjE0M2FiYTE1ZWFlMDUyNGFlMjFhYiIsImV4cCI6MTUwOTYwNDQ5OSwianRpIjoiN256WlhqQW9yd2FEVmxnSUZSZHJLQSIsImlhdCI6MTUwOTYwNDQ4NCwibmJmIjoxNTA5NjA0MzY0LCJzdWIiOiJmOWJlYmFjYjVhMjE0M2FiYTE1ZWFlMDUyNGFlMjFhYiJ9.0QCtE5XF-_FxxhjpP2sIEFU8rSnNK5jwD3BBd5oCUGc

Then we have to use this in headers for rest of the API call like:

```
function() {
    var out = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJlNjhjODJhNjY1MTQ0ZmRkOTk5YzU‌​1MjExYjYyODQ3YyIsImV‌​4cCI6MTUwMjk3NjEzNSw‌​ianRpIjoiUm1VeFdDNWh‌​QQXdvNVZ0TXFYeEFlQSI‌​sImlhdCI6MTUwMjk3NjE‌​yMCwibmJmIjoxNTAyOTc‌​2MDAwLCJzdWIiOiJlNjh‌​jODJhNjY1MTQ0ZmRkOTk‌​5YzU1MjExYjYyODQ3YyJ‌​9.h3buTcq-KATXuDF6SE‌​dA5rblvTI84_SuDZPOqd‌​m4j7Q',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    return out;
}
```

So how to integrate this to make this header generic for rest of the API calls?

Comment: use some interceptor. what f/w are you using

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to perform basic-auth: [HTTP Basic Auth Example](https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-basic-authentication-example).

Also look at the OAuth2 sample: [oauth2.feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature).

There are plenty of ways to make headers generic for all calls in Karate. Just look at the [samples](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo), for example: [headers.feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/headers.feature).

EDIT: also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205655/143475