# How to create jws message signing in karate

Tags: java-web-start, karate, signature, digital

i need to pass a header in the request which should have detached jws signed by private key (signed request payload. Is there any option in karate to do so?

or anybody did it before?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205655/143475

We have it as a demo sample now: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo (look for "JWT")

```
  * def parseJwtPayload =
  """
  function(token) {
      var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
      var base64Str = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
      var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
      var decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Str);
      var String = Java.type('java.lang.String');
      return new String(decoded);
  }
  """
```

Comment: hi Peter thanks for reply, but my ask is not for Bearer token. I am finding a way to sign a request like KJUR.jws.JWS.sign (jwt.io)

Comment: @KarateCoder that's precisely what the JWT example does: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/jwt/jwt.feature