# facing issue while implementing digest authentication in karate frame work; response:missing mandatory digest value

Tags: karate, digest-authentication

I am unable to solve below issue

error : com.intuit.karate : karateexception , response:missing mandatory digest value

while i am hitting service through postman giving 200 OK success response but the same service/end point placed in my script and executed through karate frame work i am facing above issue.

Comment: @PeterThomas you mean it is not possible to implement digest auth in karate?

Comment: if is there any way to implement please help me otherwise i will look into Rest assured frame work

Comment: please try to ask a better question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: oh yes, REST-assured may be a much better solution for you. or postman, since you are able to get it working

Comment: @PeterThomas can you please tell me the what is the difficulty in digest authentication in karate frame work?

Comment: postman is useful for manual testing , to automate micro services it won't useful i think so.

Comment: Hi Chandu, i recomend you choose a smaller more descriptive title. Also it would help if you could add the endpoint and how are you calling it in postman (except for sensible information like passwords) and how are you calling it using the script.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for HTTP digest auth in Karate. But most teams implement this using custom code, for example look at the JWT example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205655/143475