# Digest Auth in Karate - In easy way

Tags: karate

I'm not experienced in Java programming that's why I used Karate over Rest-Assured for API testing.
Unfortunately service that I'm testing is using digest authentication.

What would be the easiest way to implement digest authentication and use it in my request in Karate feature files?

Can I for example perform a call to external Java code the will use Rest-Assured build-in digest auth methods and then grab the response in my Karate feature file?

Can someone more experienced guide me trough the easiest way to authenticate my request in Karate feature test using digest auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can perform a call to external Java code. My recommendation is to ask someone for help and please note that setting up a Java function to do the authentication needed is a one time job. After that you will be up and running and this is what most teams do. The reason Karate does not bundle any auth solutions is because every team does it slightly differently. When you say "digest authentication" it can mean a whole lot of different ways.

I think this is a good reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452864/143475