How does karate handles encrypted responses?
I have a collection in which after every api call the response is encrypted and the response is decrypted to formulate the next request and so on. Is there any provision in karate to handle it?

refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46450804/143475 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65019538/143475
